# vector< vector >: verify that all have equal sizes

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Is there an std/boost algorithm to verify that all vectors within a vector have the same sizes?  And by extension, that a property of all elements is the same?

In the below examples, I use the hypothetical `std::all_equal` that I am looking for:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Line;
std::vector<Line> lines;
lines.push(Line(10));
lines.push(Line(11));

auto equalLengths = std::all_equal(lines.begin(), lines.end(), 
 [](const Line& x){ return x.size(); });
```

(And by extension:

```
std::vector<MyClass> vec;
auto equal = std::all_equal(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
 [](const MyClass& x) { return x.property(); });
```

)

Comment: You can write your own function, it won't take more than 10 lines.

Comment: If you _need_ a square vector, use _one_ vector and fake 2D indexing over the top.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just to be pedantic: rectangular vector. And I think there can be more usecases than just 2D vector. (It could be just a container of lines, where lines are represented as coefficients for normal vector in N-dimensional space, and 2D indexing doesn't make sense anymore) Otherwise I agree with Victor.

Comment: @Xarn: Oh yes, rectangular is what I meant, indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::all_of

auto const required_size = lines.front().size();
std::all_of(begin(lines), end(lines),
    [required_size](const Line& x){ return x.size() == required_size; });
```

Won't work for empty lists, unfortunately and you have to get the required size into the predicate somehow.

Comment: Slightly shorter, works for empty containers: `std::all_of(begin(lines), end(lines), [lines](const Line& x){ return x.size() == lines.front().size(); }`.

Answer (score 2):

I like @ComicSansMS's answer, but if you want a slightly less-clear approach that also works on empty vectors, you could use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) with a custom predicate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv{{3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 9}};

    bool all_same_size = std::adjacent_find(
      vv.cbegin(), 
      vv.cend(), 
      [](const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
        return a.size() != b.size();    // Look for two adjacent elements that
                                        // have different sizes
      }) == vv.cend();

    std::cout << "all same size: " << all_same_size << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Xarn I know, I know :)